# testing with testNG, spring and hsqldb

Tags: java, spring, maven, testng

i'm trying to test an application with an emmbedded memory database, hsqldb version 2.2.8.

this my test class, where i have a mistake that i don't know how to solve it.

```
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath*:applicationContext-deutes-punts-logica-Test.xml")
@Test(groups = { "logica", "models" })
public class ServeiDeutesTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {


private DbTestPreparator preparadorDb;
private IVwGptVBasicDao vwGptVBasicDAO;


/**
 * Preparació de la base de dades abans d'iniciar les provatures
 */
@BeforeMethod public void prepararProvatures() throws Exception
{
     List<Map<String,Object>> patrons;

     //Preparem la base de dades
    //eliminem i omplim
  ** preparadorDb.preparar();***
}
/*
 * Funció per recuperar deutes bàsic.
 *  
 * */
 @Test
 public void comprovarBaseDeDadesOmplerta(){

     Assert.assertNull(vwGptVBasicDAO.obtenirDeutes(null, null, null));
     Assert.assertFalse(false);
 }
```

I don't understand why i have an NULL with the object  preparadorDb;( i have get/set to Ioc correctly, i also try with autowired..)

this is the application context:

```
<bean id="connexioJdbctemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

     <!-- creació en memoria de la bbdd  
     <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"” />
     </jdbc:embedded-database>
     -->
     <bean id="serveiDeutesTest" class="cat.base.gpt.logica.test.ServeiDeutesTest">
        <property name="vwGptVBasicDAO" ref="vwGptVBasicDAO" />
        <property name="preparadorDb" ref="preparadorDb" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="gptServiceBO" class="cat.base.gpt.logica.serveis.GptService">
        <property name="vwGptVBasicDAO" ref="vwGptVBasicDAO" />
        <qualifier type="cat.base.gpt.domini.service.IGptService" value="gptServiceBO" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="vwGptVBasicDAO" class="cat.base.gpt.logica.dao.impl.VwGptVBasicDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="connexioJdbctemplate" />
    </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <!--  <property name="driverClassName" value="${cat.base.gpt.driverClassName}" />-->
         <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <!--  <property name="url" value="${cat.base.gpt.url}" />-->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:provatures" />
        <property name="username" value="SA" />
        <property name="password" value="SA" />
 </bean>

<bean id="preparadorDb" class="cat.base.baseframe.utils.test.DbTestPreparator">
    <property name="arxiusSqlCreacio">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="src/test/resources/database.sql" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="arxiusSqlCarrega">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="src/test/resources/dades.sql" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcOperations" ref="connexioJdbctemplate" />
    <!--  <property name="executarCreacio" value="${cat.base.bfp.crearTaules}" />-->
    <property name="executarCreacio" value="true" />
</bean>



    <bean id="postprocess" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:deutes-punts-logica.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:deutes-punts-test.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:entorn-servidor.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

ty.

Comment: Check your `@Component` or `@Repository` or `@Service` annotations. Maybe you forgot to add this class.

Comment: so in class cat.base.baseframe.utils.test.DbTestPreparator it's necessary this kind of annotations? ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uff well, for me this have no sense but pick up the solution.. 
finally i must specify Autowired annotation @Autowired and getter and setter!! 
maybe this is a bug? I'm pretty wasted with this situation...

```
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath*:applicationContext-deutes-punts-logica-Test.xml")
//@Test(groups = { "logica" })
public class ServeiDeutesTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private Collection collection;
    @Autowired
    private IVwGptVBasicDao vwGptVBasicDAO;
    @Autowired
    private DbTestPreparator preparadorDb;

public IVwGptVBasicDao getVwGptVBasicDAO() {
        return vwGptVBasicDAO;
    }

    public void setVwGptVBasicDAO(IVwGptVBasicDao vwGptVBasicDAO) {
        this.vwGptVBasicDAO = vwGptVBasicDAO;
    }

    public DbTestPreparator getPreparadorDb() {
        return preparadorDb;
    }

    public void setPreparadorDb(DbTestPreparator preparadorDb) {
        this.preparadorDb = preparadorDb;
    }
```

this the appCOntext

```
 <bean id="serveiDeutesTest" class="cat.base.gpt.logica.ServeiDeutesTest">
         <property name="preparadorDb" ref="preparadorDb" />
         <property name="vwGptVBasicDAO" ref="vwGptVBasicDAO" />

    </bean>

     <bean id="gptServiceBO" class="cat.base.gpt.logica.serveis.GptService">
        <property name="vwGptVBasicDAO" ref="vwGptVBasicDAO" />
        <qualifier type="cat.base.gpt.domini.service.IGptService" value="gptServiceBO" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="vwGptVBasicDAO" class="cat.base.gpt.logica.dao.impl.VwGptVBasicDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="connexioJdbctemplate" />     
    </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${cat.base.gpt.driverClassName}" />
        <!--   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />-->
        <property name="url" value="${cat.base.gpt.url}" />
        <!--  <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:provatures" />-->
        <property name="username" value="SA" />
        <property name="password" value="SA" />
 </bean>

    <!-- baseframe.utils.test.  gpt.logica--> 
<bean id="preparadorDb" class="cat.base.baseframe.utils.test.DbTestPreparator">
    <property name="arxiusSqlCreacio">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="database.sql" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="arxiusSqlCarrega">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="dades.sql" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcOperations" ref="connexioJdbctemplate" />
    <!--  <property name="executarCreacio" value="${cat.base.bfp.crearTaules}" />-->
    <property name="executarCreacio" value="${cat.base.gpt.crearTaules}" />
</bean>
```

my tstng version is =   6.7